# How do I combine a bash script that sorts, calculates an average, and prints?

Tags: bash, sorting, piping

We can't use awk or make a new file to store data.

My brain can't solve this problem. We are given a data set like this:

```
299226663 Laney Camp 70 74 71 
434401929 Skyler Camp 78 81 82 
199144454 Tracey Camp 77 84 84
```

We have to calculate the average, and print results like this:

```
71 [299226663] Camp, Laney  
80 [434401929] Camp, Skyler 
81 [199144454] Camp, Tracey
```

I have separate pieces of bash code that all work, but I can't figure out how to combine them.

This sorts the correct way

```
sort -t' ' -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1n StudentGrades.txt
```

And this next part is definitely wrong and I expect it to get torn apart, but it does compute the averages and print the correct format, except it skips the last line of StudentGrades.txt for some reason:

```
filename='StudentGrades.txt'

while read LINE
do 
var1=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f1)
var2=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f2)
var3=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f3)
var4=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f4)
var5=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f5)
var6=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f6)

let a=(var4+var5+var6)/3
echo $a [$var1] $var3, $var2 


done < StudentGrades.txt
```

I can't figure out a way to get the average, and format, and sort without moving the second script to a new file and calling a sort command on it. Any ideas? It'll probably take bigger changes because I have no faith in that second part lol.

Comment: Could you explain in words what you expect from this sorting? Sort by surname, then by id number, then finally by points? If the id number is always different, what's the point of sorting it by points with `-k1,1n`?

Comment: Yeah sort by last name, then first name if needed, then lastly ID number if needed. They'll probably give us a larger case later when there are people with the same name

Comment: Ah, sorry, so you want to sort before taking the averages. I thought that it's supposed to be some kind of ranking or something. Ok, last name, first name, id number. Makes sense.

Comment: Consider `while read number forename lastname score1 score2 score3; do …; done < "$filename"` instead of the `echo|cut` sequence.  That uses more meaningful names than `var1`..`var6` but you can stick with those if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the missing last line issue, it is a common pitfall of `read` command 
because it returns false if the line does not contain a newline code at the end 
of the line, which often occurs with the last line depending on a text editor.
As a workaround, try `while read LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]` instead of `while read LINE`.
In addition to that, consider to say `set -- $LINE` instead of splitting with `cut` command respectively. It automatically assigns each columns into positioal parameters $1, $2, and so on. Then your script will work much faster.
BTW your average calculation truncates the fractional part without rounding it to the nearest integer. Is that okay?

Summarizing above, I would modify your script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

sort -t' ' -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1n StudentGrades.txt | while read LINE || [ -n "${LINE}" ]; do
    set -- $LINE

    let a=($4*10 + $5*10 +$6*10 + 15)/30
    # If you want to preserve the 1st decimal place, replace the line above with:
    # a=$( echo $(( ($4*10 + $5*10 +$6*10 ) / 3 )) | sed -e "s/\(.\)$/.\1/" )

    echo $a [$1] $3, $2

done
```

Comment: Any ideas why the data still prints in the original order and not the sorted order?

Comment: In the previous post, the sorting process was missing and I've added it a few minutes before.  Please see the updated code and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are so sceptical about the averaging loop: except that you are flooring to integers, it looks OK.

Without any changes, more or less simply piped it all together:

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file="StudentGrades.txt"

(cat "$input_file" ; echo "") | \
sort -t' ' -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1n | \
while read LINE
do 
  var1=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f1)
  var2=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f2)
  var3=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f3)
  var4=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f4)
  var5=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f5)
  var6=$(echo $LINE | cut -d' ' -f6)

  let a=(var4+var5+var6)/3
  echo $a [$var1] $var3, $var2 
done
```

The `echo ""` after `cat` is needed only in the case that the last line of the file is not read properly (this happens because `read` waits for a linebreak, but your file probably does not end with a linebreak).

The `\` symbols make it appear as if there is no line break in the code, so that the commands are piped together. By adding enough semicolons, you could even write it in one line, if you really wanted to.

---

With refactoring proposed by @JonathanLeffler :

```
#!/bin/bash
input_file="StudentGrades.txt"

(cat "$input_file" ; echo "") | \
sort -t' ' -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1n | \
while read num_id name surname points1 points2 points3
do 
  let average=(points1+points2+points3)/3
  echo ${average} [${num_id}] $surname, $name
done
```

Seems to work just like the other version.

Hah, learnt something new in bash! Thank you @JonathanLeffler! :)

Comment: I am getting the error "cat: : No such file or directory", and it also does not sort anymore, it only prints in the order the data came in. Also the average doesn't need to be accurate.

Comment: I fixed the cat error, but the sorting is still an issue.

Comment: @grilam14: what character do you have between the two single quotes in your `sort` command?  Is your file tab separated or blank separated?  Do you really need to specify a delimiter (Do you have name components with blanks in them while the fields are tab separated, for example?)  That would be an easy way for your sort to be failing.